# Selenium/splinter taking a browser screenshot not working

Tags: linux, selenium, permissions, splinter

I have a script that using splinter to take a screenshot of a certain page.
When I run this script on my home computer (ubuntu) it works perfectly fine (takes the screenshot). When I run it on the terminal (debiuan - sudo python) on my server it also works fine.
However, when I have it run the script on the server it does not seem to be able to save the picture.

Why is this?
I am inclined to say that python does not have write permissions but I run the python script with sudo and I chmod 777 the directory, but it still is not able to save the picture.

Is there any other way I have to give python permissions or is this not a permission issue?

The line where splinter is taking a picture is

```
browser.driver.save_screenshot('picture.png')
```

Comment: What if you put an absolute path to the image? Thanks.

Comment: WOW. That was it. Thank you so much

Comment: Works for me :) Cheers!!